# Randomly remove image from game space without using class in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, random, fadeout

I am trying to have the Moles (little cubes in https://jsfiddle.net/JennyF/s4rteuks/13/) randomly disappear form the `#gamespace` if they are not clicked on. They randomly appear between 0 - 2 seconds. The game is working on Firefox without this question addressed while including my attempt, but it is not working in JSFiddle.

```
      function addMole(){
        xPos=randPosX();
        yPos=randPosY();
        $("#gamespace").append('<img src="img/mole.png" style="top:'+xPos+'px; left:'+yPos+'px;" />');
        var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*(2000));
        t=setTimeout("addMole();", r);
        var count=0;
        setTimeout("remove()", 1000);
        function remove(){
            $("#gamespace").append("<img id='img"+count+"'></img>");
            count++;
            setTimeout("remove()", 1000);
        };
    };//end mole
```

My instructor told us not to use a `class` and gave us this example. Obviously, I want to `fadeOut` instead of add anything. And I don't have any `<p>` tags. I just don't know what to put in their place. Or if I totally messed it up.

```
var count=0;
setTimeout("add()", 1000);
function add(){
$("div#div1").append("<p id='p"+count+"'></p>");
count++;
  setTimeout("add()", 1000);}
```

Comment: fadeOut is happening by reducing opacity attribute of the element

Comment: I tried changing it to `remove` but it didn't matter.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that in your remove function, you have the img tag closing with `</imag>` instead of `</img>`

Comment: Thanks, I just edited that here, it isn't what I have on my text editor.

Comment: Geez, is it that bad of a question? I've tried various things to no avail. At least tell me how to fix the question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is the corrected code and my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JennyF/s4rteuks/14/, which doesn't work, it works in my program, though. I don't know what I'm doing wrong in jsfiddle. I copied everything exactly and attached the right jQuery library.

```
    function addMole(){
        if (time_left >0){
            xPos=randPosX();
            yPos=randPosY();
            $("#gamespace").append('<img id='+count+' src="img/mole.png" style="top:'+xPos+'px; left:'+yPos+'px;" />');
            var f='#'+count;
            count++;                
            $("#gamespace").find(f).delay(1500).fadeOut();
            var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*(2000));
            t=setTimeout("addMole();", r);
            }else{
                clearTimeout(t);
                $("#gamespace").off("click", "img");
            };//end if
    };//end mole
```

Comment: You're code does not *remove* the img, it simply sets the opacity/display to take up no space (it's *virtually* invisible, but still in the DOM).

Comment: I just changed it for the fiddle because I didn't know how to add jQueryUI in my game it's `.effect("explode")`  ....Oh, you're talking about the `.fadeOut()` . I didn't know that's all we had to do for the project. They aren't clickable for points after they fade out. This is my first project ever.